# How to call a function that takes multiple arguments with a list of arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a function which is

```
def abc(a,b,c):
    #do something
    pass
```

I would like to call this with a list instead of `abc(a,b,c)`, e.g.:

```
abc([1,2,3])
```

I cannot change the definition of `abc`.

Use case:

I am trying to write my own eval using the `ast` library

While implementing the `ast.Call`, I would like to be able to call my functions with multiple arguments.

However, if node is of type `ast.Call`, the arguments are passed in the form of a list.

E.g.:

```
>> exp = ast.parse('abc(1,2)', mode='eval').body
>> exp
# <_ast.Call at 0x2ab3c5bef7d0>
>> exp.args
#[<_ast.Num at 0x2ab3c5bef850>, <_ast.Num at 0x2ab3c5bef890>]
```

The problem is, I cannot understand how to call a function whose name is `abc` when the args returned to me is a list.

I would be trying to call library functions like `min`, `max`, `len`, `str` and my own functions like `contains`, `get_item` etc. What I can't understand is, how do I pass a list of arguments to a function that takes multiple arguments?

Comment: i did not know the term unpacking. thank you.

Comment: Yeah it can sometimes be hard to find the relevant information, if you lack the terminology. There's more about this in python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists . I recommend reading that whole page :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follows, by unpacking the list with `*`

```
>>> def abc(a,b,c): print(a,b,c)
...
>>> abc(1,2,3)
1 2 3
>>> abc(*[1,2,3])
1 2 3
```